# Python: cannot load class from my module

Tags: python, module

EDIT:
I couldn't use my own modules. It was a stupid waste of time. If you ever have the same problem, try reading this first:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/

I just started OOP with Python and I am confused by modules and classes.

I work with a Mac and I can write my own modules and load them from the site-packages folder.

Now I would like to create modules with useful classes.
`import custom_module` works.
But if `custom_module` has a class `Custom_class`, things don't work.

I tried doing:
(EDIT: I am sorry, I am removing old code which was made up, this is what I just used and doesn't work)

in custommodule.py:

```
class Customclass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

This module loads without errors.
Then I get:

```
new = custommodule.Customclass('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Customclass'
```

BTW, I started trying to do this using code from this [tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes)

I was not able to get over this. Please advise, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the code for `custom_module`?

Comment: Could you edit it into your question?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What I'm getting is `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment`, not AttributeError. Please fix your question.

Comment: I removed "counter", it was basically vestigial code from the tutorial I was following. It was not fundamental, I can't use the class at all anyway.

Comment: In the first part, it says that you have `custom_module` and `Custom_class`. (well `custom_Class`) in your actual code. After the edit, it say `custommodule` and `Customclass`. Could you please verify which is correct.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I removed the old code.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure that all of the files are accessible, ie: `custommodule` is in the same folder as the file you are working in?

Comment: Try to execute, in the python interpreter, the command `dir (custommodule)` after you import `custommodule`, it should print what you just imported. The code you posted seems good and it work as expected

Comment: import custommodule works, i.e. does not return errors

Comment: Gianluca, this is the result:

`>>> import custommodule

>>> dir (custommodule)

['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']`

Comment: michaelpri, I am using the interpreter from the Desktop.
The module is in:

~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/custommodule

Comment: Then you are importing something wrong, it should be (given your code example) `['Customclass', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']` which is what I get trying your code

Comment: To create the module I am putting custommodule.py in its own folder in

~/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/

and adding __init__.py

Is there any step I left out?

Comment: `from custom_module import CustomClass`? and then `new = CustomClass('foo')`?

Comment: >>> import custommodule 
>>> from custommodule import Customclass  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
ImportError: cannot import name Customclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this file layout

```
site-packages/custommodule/__init__.py
site-packages/custommodule/custommodule.py
```

you are creating a package named `custommodule` that contains a module *also* named `custommodule`. Your code needs to look like

```
import custommodule
# or more specifically,
# import custommodule.custommodule
new = custommodule.custommodule.Customclass('foo')
```

or

```
from custommmodule import custommodule
new = custommodule.Customclass('foo')
```

You can also put `custommodule.py` directly in `site-packages` to avoid creating the package, in which case your original code should work.

Comment: >>> from utils1.utils1 import helloFoo
>>> helloFoo()
foo

This just worked!!!!!!!!

Comment: THANKS! I didn't realise that I had to specify the package as well.
Now ALL my modules work and I can call functions and classes correctly!

Answer (score 1):

For me, at least, this works `from mod_name import ClassName`
[image: mod2]
[image: mod1]
[image: Runs fine]

When I run this code I don't get any errors. Hope this helped

EDIT: also make sure that the module you want to import is in the project directory. If you view the left panel in the images both modules are in `Stack`. I hope this is obvious but, the class needs to be in the module you import as well. Make sure that the class you're importing does not import the class your importing in because then you get circular dependencies.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks, I am not familiar with Pycharm.

My modules on Mac OS are in PYTHONPATH. And I can load them without errors (they are found), but that's the only things that works.  

Maybe there is something wrong in the way I am organising files? Maybe I need something more than __init__.py?

Comment: Which IDE are you using? And your classes are created properly. It is probably something to do with the organization.

Comment: I never used an IDE. I just use Textwrangler on Mac.

Comment: That's very strange. Firstly, I'd highly recommenced an IDE like pycharm. Secondly, I'm stumped!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

File *custommodule.py* in the directory custommodule

```
class Customclass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

File `__init__.py` int he custommodule directory

```
from .custommodule import CustomClass
```

Note the dot *before* custommodule. This force the init to load the module from the same directory.

Without the dot, it work under python2 but not under python3

Comment: This is strange.
I tried doing the import from the same directory (customodule itself!) and it worked, but it doesn't work with what you suggested.



>>> from .custommodule import CustomClass  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
>>> import custommodule
>>> from custommodule import Customclass

Comment: You cannot do this way, since a relative import seems to be allowed only in a package. the line `from .custommodule import CustomClass` is in the `__init__.py` file, you cannot use it from the interpreter